# Java Printing with Template

Tags: java, templates, printing, jasper-reports

I have an application that was developed in .NET and I'm moving it to a Java environment.  The application (amongst other things) prints double elimination brackets, filling in the team/contestant name.  I'm looking to do the same, but be able to swap out the brackets for a different system (single elimination, etc).  The old program draws out the entire bracket and I was thinking that it would be easier to create a bracket template and just place the data in the template prior to printing.

Doing a search, I found a lot of recommendations for Jasper Reports.  I've looked into it and it seems to be a really powerful reporting engine, which is way more than I need.  Is there a smaller, simpler print templating library out there?  I need to be able to print from both Windows and Mac platforms.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: +1 for JasperReports.  Even for simple jobs, will save a many, many hours of work. IMHO

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/jmte/. I've never used it but it seems to fill the gap you're looking for.

Comment: I may be missing something, but it doesn't look like Jasper will help me.  Using iReport to create a report, it runs every record through the Detail Band.  What I need is to particularly be able to say "Put the NAME for record 1 here", "put the NAME for record 2 here", etc.